# How to disable Akka Dead Letters warnings in Tests

Tags: akka, akka-stream, akka-testkit

I recently upgraded to Akka 2.6.10. Now I'm seeing a lot of warnings like this when I run tests for my actors with `ActorTestKit`:

```
[WARN] [12/16/2020 09:03:14.995] [AsyncTestWithControlledTime-akka.actor.internal-dispatcher-3] [akka://AsyncTestWithControlledTime/user/$a] received dead letter: GotCriticalFailure(my custom error message,akka.stream.AbruptStageTerminationException: GraphStage [akka.stream.impl.ActorRefSinkStage$$anon$1@15cc9eaa] terminated abruptly, caused by for example materializer or actor system termination.)
```

AyncTestWithControlledTime is a class I wrote and is a super class of all my tests. It creates the test kit and provides the config for the actor sytem. However, trying to suppress the warnings via the config, for instance with `akka.log-dead-letters = off`, does not help.

I usually receive the warnings when my actor has subscribed to a stream and the test finishes so the stream is not properly cancelled.

How can I disable the warnings. It would be best if I could suppress them only when the test is finished and the test kit actor system is shut down.

Comment: I am not sure if adding `akka.log-dead-letters = off` is a solution. The docs (https://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/current/akka/stream/AbruptStageTerminationException.html) state that your `GraphStageLogic without any of the handler callbacks`. Maybe if you find the `GraphStage` in your project and make sure that they have a `try {} catch { case e: Throwable => failStage(e) }`. I think this is where your problem is comming.

Answer (score 1):

That log entry is from the `akka.testkit.TestEventListener` (or some subclass of it) part of the Akka testkit, it is only present if you have explicitly enabled it through config with `akka.loggers = ["akka.testkit.TestEventListener"]`.

The `akka.log-dead-letters` setting only has effect on the default dead letter handler, not the testkit one.

If you don't use the logging testkit you can simply remove that config from your config in the test, if you use it you can perhaps use `TestEvent.Mute` with a filter for that specific warning. `Mute` is published on the event bus and picked up by the `TestEventListener`.